# Рекурсии хвостовая и традиционная?

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Никак не могу разобраться, чем друг от друга отличаются.
Правильно ли я понимаю, принцип работы традиционной рекурсии - это только передача значения, поэтому традиционная не ограничивается размером стека и вполне может себе позволить зациклиться, в то время как хвостовая хранит в стеке адреса перехода, а также промежуточное значение, что может привести к переполнению стека, т.о. хвостовую можно рассмотреть как обычный цикл? Если так, то в чем преимущества традиционной или хвостовой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сказал, что хвостовая (оконечная) рекурсия - это просто частный случай рекурсии вообще, и уж говорить о том, что обычная рекурсия может зациклиться, а хвостовая - нет, или что стек переполняется в одном случае, и не переполняется в другом - ерунда.

Просто хвостовая рекурсия - когда единственный рекурсивный вызов находится в самом конце, перед выходом их функции, и такая рекурсия *легко* преобразуется в итерацию. Часто просто самим компилятором...

Comment: А традиционная не в самом конце? Нашел еще, что единственное их различие в том, что хвостовая сначала вычисляет, потом делает вызов, а традиционная сначала ждет рекурсивного вызова, а потом вычисляет...

Comment: Кстати, [из Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F): *Хвостовая рекурсия — частный случай рекурсии, при котором любой рекурсивный вызов является последней операцией перед возвратом из функции.* Только и всего.